# Issue with Cassandra lightweight transaction

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I am seeing some interesting behavior with Cassandra lightweight transactions in a standalone Cassandra instance. I am using DataStax Enterprize 5.0.2 for my testing. The issue is, a table being updated using lightweight transaction is returning true, which means it is updated. But a subsequent query on the same table shows that the row is NOT updated. Please note that I tried the same in a clustered environment and it worked absolutely fine! So I am just trying to understand what's going wrong in my environment.

Here is a simple example of what I am doing.

I create a simple table as provided below:

```
CREATE TABLE smart.TOPICSCONSUMERASSNSTATUS (
    TOPNM text,
    PARTID int,
    STATUS text,
    PRIMARY KEY (TOPNM,PARTID)
);
```

I I put the following set of preload data for testing purpose:

```
insert into smart.topicsconsumerassnstatus (topnm, partid, status) values ('ESP', 0, 'UNASSIGNED');
insert into smart.topicsconsumerassnstatus (topnm, partid, status) values ('ESP', 1, 'UNASSIGNED');
insert into smart.topicsconsumerassnstatus (topnm, partid, status) values  ('ESP', 2, 'UNASSIGNED');
insert into smart.topicsconsumerassnstatus (topnm, partid, status) values ('ESP', 3, 'UNASSIGNED');
insert into smart.topicsconsumerassnstatus (topnm, partid, status) values ('ESP', 4, 'UNASSIGNED');
```

Now, I put the first select statement to get the details from the table:

```
select * from smart.topicsconsumerassnstatus where topnm='ESP';
```

It lists all partids with status UNASSIGNED. To assign partid 0, I then fire the following update statement:

```
update smart.topicsconsumerassnstatus set status='ASSIGNED' where topnm='ESP' and partid=0 if status='UNASSIGNED';
```

It returns true. And now, when I fire the above select query again, it lists all 5 rows with status UNASSIGNED. Interestingly, repeated execution of the update statement keeps returning true all the time - this clearly mean that actual data is not getting updated in the table.

I have seen the query trace as well and the update seems to be working fine as CAS is returned successful.

Also note that this behavior is seen explicitly when a query is used with "allow filtering" at least once, and from then on...

Can anyone please put some lights on what could be the issue? Is it something to do with "allow filtering" clause?

Comment: I can't reproduce this with the latest 3.0 release. When exactly do you execute "allow filtering" queries in the scenario described above?

Comment: You could also run the statements with `TRACING ON` in cqlsh to get an idea of what's happening when you issue the commands.